# (ibm_db) ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, db2, python-3.8

I have installed Python 3.8.1 and have installed the ibm_db 3.0.1 API for IBM DB2.
When I try to 'import ibm_db' in debug mode I get

```
"ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified
module could not be found."
```

I tried uninstalling and re-installing Python and the API, installing prior versions of Python but nothing worked.
I also tried to see if adding the path prior to the import ibm_db would make a difference:

```
sys.path.append(
    "C:\\Users\\<userid>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\ibm_db")
```

It should not be that hard so please feel free to suggest what might be considered obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 16/June/2020, the ibm_db module versions 3.0.2 and higher now supports Python 3.8 on Microsoft Windows platform.

The ibm_db module versions lower than v3.0.2 do not support Python 3.8 on Microsoft-Windows.

You can see this mentioned on the related github issue [github](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/433).

ibm_db v3.0.1 will install and work correctly with Python 3.7.x on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Installing Python 3.7.6 solved the issue, I am now able to import Ibm_db 3.0.1 and run without errors. Thank you for responding.

Comment: @Syafiqur__  Make a new question: give all details of your Windows config, whether Visual-Studio is installed and which version. In particular show the command-line you used for installing ibm_db, and __all__ of its output as plain text (no graphic images).

Comment: I have. [This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672647/db2-driver-for-django?noredirect=1#comment109181267_61672647) @mao

Comment: According to that question, that is a different symptom, so I will not respond further in this thread.