# Db2 driver for Django?

Tags: python, django, db2, pyodbc

It seems to me that Django currenty only provides 4 backend database engine which are:

1. 'django.db.backends.postgresql'
2. 'django.db.backends.mysql'
3. 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
4. 'django.db.backends.oracle'

If I use MySQL, all I have to do is just fill the `Engine` with `'django.db.backends.mysql'`. But now, because my main Database is DB2, I'm having some issues to connect it with pyodbc. What is needed?

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = 'o0zdmzzdw44tkd5a7o*h-@*bo)r@f#)!)$)8f-y%=sn*kr)@t%'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [127.0.0.1]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'arapi.apps.ArapiConfig', #my projeck
    'rest-framework', 
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'arDRFAPIWEB.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'arDRFAPIWEB.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'ibm_db_django',
          'NAME': as400,
          'USER' : root,
          'PASSWORD' : root,
          'HOST' : as400.****.co.id,
          'PORT' : 3306,
          'PCONNECT'   :  True, #Optional property, default is false
      }
   }

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

When I run `python manage.py test` I got this error

> Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
>       'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Although I've downgrade the `python into 3.6.5` version and my `django is 2.1.1` version which I thought this might solve the problem.

Comment: I use `ibm_db_django` version 1.2.0.0 with Django 2.2.5 with Db2-LUW on Linux x64 with python 3.6.9 in a virtualenv.
In my `settings.py` I needed to remove(comment-out) the `USE_TZ=True` and add `django.contrib.sites` and `SITE_ID=1` for my test-app to run.  Looks like the `ibm_db_django` has not been updated on github for quite some time and the docs are poor and support for more recent django version and recent python versions is not yet available. If you are connecting to AS400 (Db2 for i) you will need a license file, unless you connect via a Db2-connect gateway.

Comment: I'm using windows, does it make any different? What is Db2-LUW? And what kind of license file do I need? I think what I needed is DB2 Bakcend that located in `~lib/site-package/django/db/backend`

Comment: Db2-LUW is Db2 server on Linux/Unix/Windows. License-file only needed if you are using the default clidriver and not using Db2-connect-gateway. Licence file NOT needed if using the `IBM i access` with odbc option.

Comment: I recommend that before you try with django, you get the ODBC connection to your database working via the (matching bitness) odbcad32 tool on MS-Windows. That will prove odbc connects and works regardless of python. Next,  At the present date (May 2020), the ibm_db_django module supports a maximum django version of 2.0.0 according to its readme on github. If you uninstall your django 2.1.1 and install 2.0.0 , and create a __new__ project (django_admin startproject),  and merge your settings.py changes into the this settings.py, you may get a different result.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Django driver available for IBM Db2. It is even [referenced in the Db2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/c0054366.html) and there is a document which describes the [setup procedure for Db2 and Django](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0060891.html). There, they suggest a configuration like this:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
  'ENGINE'   : 'ibm_db_django',
  'NAME'     : 'database',
  'USER'     : 'user',
  'PASSWORD' : 'password',
  'HOST'     : 'localhost',
  'PORT'     : '50000',
  'PCONNECT' :  True,      #Optional property. It is true by default
  }
}
```

You can find the driver [package ibm_db_django](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django) in the related GitHub repo.

You need to specify `ibm_db_django` instead of, e.g., `django.db.backends.mysql`. `django.db.backends.db2` will give an error.

Comment: I've tried that too. But still got the same error `Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'`

Comment: Seen this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#using-a-3rd-party-database-backend

Comment: Share your code if you have problems configuring it

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who have the same problem:

This error is because of version compatibility issue in Django, ibm_db and ibm_db_django

My current versions on windows is:

Python 3.8

ibm_db 3.1

ibm_db_django 1.5.3.0

Django 4.2

and on Ubuntu version of ibm_db 3.2 worked correctly.

Note that the prerequisite for Django on python is introduced in [main Github page of ibm_db_django](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb-django#prerequisites-for-django-on-python):

Django Framework 2.2.0 or 3.1 or 3.2 or 4.2